# count successive occurences in a time series without df.iterrows()

Tags: pandas, vectorization, sequential-number

Given a dataframe with a time series like this:

| time | event |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 12:00:01 | NaN |
| 2020-01-01 12:00:02 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 12:00:03 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 12:00:04 | NaN |
| 2020-01-01 12:00:05 | NaN |
| 2020-01-01 12:00:06 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 12:00:07 | Nan |

I would like to get a summary-dataframe like:

| event_id | time_start | time_stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 | 2020-01-01 12:00:01 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 12:00:02 | 2020-01-01 12:00:04 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 12:00:06 | 2020-01-01 12:00:07 |

In a step-by-step approach I think I should first add an empty column 'event_i',
then fill in the index of the events (1,2,3,...)
Once this works, I can try to create a summary-dataframe.
I am already stuck at giving the index to the events.

I could work something out with df.iterrows() but that is not recommended.
**How can I vectorize this indexing-procedure?**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# define mini-dataset as an example
data= {'time': ['2020-01-01 12:00:00', '2020-01-01 12:00:01', '2020-01-01 12:00:02','2020-01-01 12:00:03',
              '2020-01-01 12:00:04','2020-01-01 12:00:05', '2020-01-01 12:00:06', '2020-01-01 12:00:07',
              '2020-01-01 12:00:08', '2020-01-01 12:00:09','2020-01-01 12:00:10'],
     'event': [1,np.nan,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,1,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time']=pd.to_datetime((df['time']))

# give a sequential number to each event
df['event_i'] = np.nan

# for each event-number, group by and stack: event_id,  time_start time_stop
# ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can do better without cumulative operations and grouping, as in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76846405/14909621). All we need is shifting and comparison, which are easy and can be vectorized:

```
# transform 1 to True, Nan to False
event = df['event'].notna()
previous = event.shift()

# mark start and stop point by comparing neighbors
start = (event > previous)
stop = (event < previous)

# care about corner cases at the first and last positions
start.iloc[0] = event.iloc[0]
stop.iloc[-1] = event.iloc[-1]

# extract data by prepared indexers
answer = pd.DataFrame({
    'time_start': time[start].values,
    'time_stop': time[stop].values})
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Code

```
# Create a grouper to mark the intervals of successive events
m = df['event'].isna()
b = m.cumsum().mask(m).ffill(limit=1)

# group the time column by the grouper and agregate with first and last
df1 = df['time'].groupby(b).agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Create event id column
df1['event_id'] = df1.index + 1
```

---

```
                first                last  event_id
0 2020-01-01 12:00:00 2020-01-01 12:00:01         1
1 2020-01-01 12:00:02 2020-01-01 12:00:04         2
2 2020-01-01 12:00:06 2020-01-01 12:00:07         3
3 2020-01-01 12:00:08 2020-01-01 12:00:10         4
```